# Keyword Analyser

Tags: php, regex, analysis, text-manipulation, text-analysis

I want to know any algorithms or php code for working out keyword competition. The keyword can be used multiple sites per website and on multiple websites. I want to know how its ranking can be worked out.

Thanks

Comment: you want us to build you a search engine?

Comment: @dqhendricks - "you should get the idea" - I like how we are expected to do this for him ha

Comment: This is really two questions; you may have 1 "problem" but you need to separate distinct questions.  Your second question here isn't worth asking in a new question (it's been [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) and would likely be closed as a duplicate pretty quickly). To that end, I'd suggest editing this question and removing your second paragraph.

Comment: @seth.vargo I like how you feel that I expected you to do this for me. I expected people willing to help to help me. You could have rather given me the answer and I would have said thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a search engine? That's a pretty ambitious task. Quite a lot to ask over a volunteer driven PHP thread.
Since I'm a nice guy, I'll give you the Regex for free, but you'll have to do some digging to build that search engine you want.

```
/<title>([^<])*</title>/gi
```

If you really are serious about the SE, try starting with [this article from O'Rilley](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2002/10/24/simplesearchengine.html).

Comment: i wouldn't use a regex for getting a title tag. instead I would use the PHP DOM classes to parse html, and grab the title contents.

Comment: @dqhendricks, why not? php dom might not deal with broken title tags.

Comment: @phpmycoder, i am not building a search engine (bit too far fetched for me right now), I have my website domainsoutlook.com where I am doing keyword analysis for websites and just need to analyse keywords for that.

Comment: @user381595 you should never try to parse a structured language with regex... here is a rather famous answer as to why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @dqhendricks Point taken. In this application, I think the overhead of loading a PHP DOM class and parsing a document for one lousy title tag is a little too much. Besides, the regex won't break unless the code is invalid, which would cause the DOM interpreter to break too.

Comment: @dqhendricks Ironically, most of the open source PHP DOM interpreter classes use regexes to parse. This is not true of PHP DOM or libxml.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: I think you'll find most parsers of any kind use regular expressions somewhere, but HTML is not a regular language and cannot be parsed with regex alone.  The point is that you need to deal with nesting. ...and most modern parsers can deal with some malformed code.

Answer (score 0):

[Try get_meta_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php)

**Example #2 What get_meta_tags() returns (taken from the manual)**

```
<?php
// Assuming the above tags are at www.example.com
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.example.com/');

// Notice how the keys are all lowercase now, and
// how . was replaced by _ in the key.
echo $tags['author'];       // name
echo $tags['keywords'];     // php documentation
echo $tags['description'];  // a php manual
echo $tags['geo_position']; // 49.33;-86.59
?>
```